# RDP Client for Android

Tags: android, rdp

Im searching code for RDP Client(OpenSource Google code for Android). Im Strugling to start,

Suggest me, how to start this project?
kumar

Answer (score 1):

The RDP protocol is developed by Microsoft, and the first place to start is with the specification documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445.aspx

Once you have understood the specification you can design your application to implement them in alignment with the target audience and their specific needs.

There are already RDP client applications available such as Xtralogic, so you should ask if you have or can you identify a real differentiator that will bring people to your app over other already well established and functional ones?

It is a huge project and not something anyone here can (or probably will) write source code for you.  I'm sure they will however help with small specific questions related to the overall project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is there any google code link for working rdp client?

Comment: The only two I know are xrdp and rdeskotp (which xrdp is based on) - they are not mobile specific but might be a good starting point